# How to trigger azure function when there is a message in Kafka topic

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, azure-functions

I am new to azure function and Kafka.

I would like to know whether it is possible to trigger azure function when there is message in the Kafka topic?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure Functions need a trigger defined in order to run. There is a limited set of supported trigger types, and Kafka is not one of them.

In order to consume messages from Kafka, you would first need to send them to a supported source (e.g. Azure Event Hubs) and configure Functions to listen to that new source.

Comment: Thank you. How to send kafka message to Azure Event Hubs? sorry if this is silly :)

Comment: It's not silly... I've seen [Kafka MirrorMaker with Event Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-kafka-mirror-maker-tutorial) but haven't used it myself

Comment: Its old answer... Nowadays Azure Functions has trigger and sender for Kafka.

Answer (score 11):

Azure have an extension for Kafka.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-kafka-extension

;)

Comment: DISCLAIMER: This library is supported in the Premium Plan along with support for scaling...

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, even though this question is old: In case you are using Confluent Platform, there is also a SinkConnector that triggers an AzureFunction (via HTTP trigger).